# Doxygen \command does not work, but @command does

Tags: doxygen

For example, the following works:

```
/** @brief Some info
    @todo A todo task
    @author Me
*/
```

But this does not:

```
/** \brief Some info
    \todo A todo task
    \author Me
*/
```

Am I missing any Doxyfile config? Thank you!

Comment: I placed both constructs in a .h file, added below each a prototype of a function, added a @file command and used a default Doxyfile all in doxygen version 1.8.9.1 and everything was fine. So some more in depth information about what you tried and the doxygen version is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, at the end, it was just a matter of Doxygen versions, as I was using a Doxyfile version 1.7.2 and my Doxygen version is 1.8.6. After updating the doxyfile to my Doxygen version it worked.